# Transferring selected rows between tables in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a simple table in angular 2 using the angular material.

I have implemented transferring selected rows functionality from the first table to the second table and deleting the selected rows from the second table.

As I select rows from the first table and click on button **Move To Second Table** , the selected rows are transferred to the second table but are not getting spliced from the first table, although I have spliced the selected rows in the **transferSelectedRows()** method.

please access my sample app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-au6ho8?file=app%2Faccount.component.scss)...

Comment: you don't splice it from the table, you do splice it from selection...

Comment: yes i spliced from selection ,,, but not getting spliced.....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the changes you need to do in your component side (Please also read the comments)

**Component Side :**

```
uncheckedData = this.data; // to maintain data for table 1

transferSelectedRows() {
    this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
        let index: number = this.uncheckedData.findIndex(d => d === item);

        this.checkedData.push(this.uncheckedData[index]); // adding to table 2
        this.uncheckedData.splice(index,1); // remove data from table 1

    });

    this.selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.uncheckedData);
    this.checkedDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.checkedData);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.checkedDataSource.paginator = this.checkedpaginator;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap)**

Comment: hmm yes ........... even i need to move it from 2-->1 ........ i will try it.. if any problem exist i will come back again ..... thanks a lot..

Comment: @Heena , Glad that hepled you , Happy coding BTW.

Comment: can you also tell me how to push from 2-->1

Comment: @Heena , please check the demo again I have updated the demo

Comment: @Heena Check again , it will be added last so you have to go to 2nd page to check that.

Comment: oh... sry .. yes i am getting

Comment: Hello Sir .. can you please check this question ,,.,,,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609355/transferring-rows-from-one-table-to-another-in-angular-2-using-angular-material