# Transferring Rows from one table to another in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have implemented simple table in angular 2 using angular material...I have taken two mat-table where the selected rows from first table are transferred to second table on clicking Move To Table 2 and vice versa on clicking Move To Table 1

But as I select and Click on Move To Table 2 , the row from my first table is getting spliced and transferred but as do the same for the second row, I am getting the previously transferred row again in my second table.

[Sample Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-mlqthx?file=app%2Faccount.component.html)

### Below shown is my output.

Initially when I transfer first row , its getting spliced and moved to second table .
[image]

But when I transfer second row ,the previously moved row is again added in the second table.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are not clearing the selection ,

All you need to do is clear the selection once the transfer from one table to another is finished

Add `this.selection.clear();` this at the end of `moveToTableTwo()` , like :

```
moveToTableTwo(){
   ...
   this.selection.clear();
}
```

Comment: yes its working now ,,but rows from table 2 are moved to table 1

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the selection did not allow me to move the checked items back to table 1. This worked for me instead:

```
moveToTableTwo(){
   ...
   this.selection.deselect;
}
```

Comment: This solution stopped moving the previously selected item across. However upon inspecting it further, it's possible to copy the same item over again if the button is clicked, without anything being checked.